# Python invalid pointer error after running for a few days

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have this script on a Raspberry Pi that runs forever and every minute will get data from my weather station and then post it to a JSON and database. The issue is that after a few days of running, the Python script stops running with the following error:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted
```

Here is the code:

```py
from gpiozero import Button
import bme280_sensor
import wind_direction_byo
import ds18b20_therm
import statistics
import time
import math
import json
import database
import gc

CM_IN_A_KM = 100000.0
SECS_IN_AN_HOUR = 3600
ADJUSTMENT = 1.18
BUCKET_SIZE = 0.2794

store_speeds = []
store_directions = []

wind_count = 0
rain_count = 0
radius_cm = 9.0
wind_interval = 5
interval = 60

db = database.weather_database()

def spin():
        global wind_count
        wind_count = wind_count + 1
        # print("spin" + str(wind_count))

def calculate_speed(time_sec):
        global wind_count
        circumference_cm = (2 * math.pi) * radius_cm
        rotations = wind_count / 2.0

        dist_km = (circumference_cm * rotations) / CM_IN_A_KM

        km_per_sec = dist_km / time_sec
        km_per_hour = km_per_sec * SECS_IN_AN_HOUR

        return km_per_hour * ADJUSTMENT

wind_speed_sensor = Button(5)
wind_speed_sensor.when_pressed = spin

def reset_wind():
        global wind_count
        wind_count = 0

def bucket_tipped():
        global rain_count
        rain_count = rain_count + 1

def reset_rainfall():
        global rain_count
        rain_count = 0

def updateJsonFile(wind_average, wind_speed, wind_gust, rainfall, humidity, pressure, ambient_temp, ground_temp):
        jsonFile = open("/var/www/html/weatherdata.json", "r")
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
        jsonFile.close()

        tmp = data["ambient_temp"]
        data["ambient_temp"] = ambient_temp
        data["humidity"] = humidity
        data["pressure"] = pressure
        data["ground_temp"] = ground_temp
        data["rainfall"] = rainfall
        data["wind_average"] = wind_average
        data["wind_speed"] = wind_speed
        data["wind_gust"] = wind_gust
        data["timestamp"] = time.time()

        jsonFile = open("/var/www/html/weatherdata.json", "w+")
        jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
        jsonFile.close()


rain_sensor = Button(6)
rain_sensor.when_pressed = bucket_tipped

temp_probe = ds18b20_therm.DS18B20()

while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time <= interval:
                wind_start_time = time.time()
                reset_wind()
                #time.sleep(wind_interval)
                while time.time() - wind_start_time <= wind_interval:
                        store_directions.append(wind_direction_byo.get_value())

                final_speed = calculate_speed(wind_interval)
                store_speeds.append(final_speed)

        wind_average = wind_direction_byo.get_average(store_directions)
        wind_gust = max(store_speeds)
        wind_speed = statistics.mean(store_speeds)
        rainfall = rain_count * BUCKET_SIZE
        reset_rainfall()
        humidity, pressure, ambient_temp = bme280_sensor.read_all()
        ground_temp = temp_probe.read_temp()

        #print(wind_average, wind_speed, wind_gust, rainfall, humidity, pressure, ambient_temp, ground_temp)
        updateJsonFile(wind_average, wind_speed, wind_gust, rainfall, humidity, pressure, ambient_temp, ground_temp)
        db.insert(ambient_temp, ground_temp, 0, pressure, humidity, wind_average, wind_speed, wind_gust, rainfall)

        store_speeds = []
        store_directions = []
        gc.collect()
```

Most of the code is taken from [Raspberry Pi's Weather Station guide](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-your-own-weather-station/9). My addition is the `updateJsonFile` function and some other little things to get that to work. The website doesn't mention this problem however there was other errors in the guide they didn't mention.

My guess is that it's running out of memory (despite the garbage collect) considering the timing of when the error happens. I'm going to investigate that but if anyone else has a solution, that would be great.

Comment: I think garbage collection is actually the problem. Maybe change to `gc.collect(generation=1)` or maybe even `generation=0`. `gc.collect()` returns items that cannot be freed. Maybe storing that in a log will help you track down the issue. Somewhere `gc.collect()` is calling `free()` and when it does the original pointer that was passed to `malloc` has been changed in some way. This is why you are getting this error. The pointer has to be identical to the original to be `free'd`. This is a "way down at the core" problem that you need to handle.

Comment: To be a little clearer, my theory is that `gc` runs but cannot free something (for whatever reason), that thing gets changed and `gc` decides it can free it (for some other reason), and throws the error. According to the docs, `float` is something that might not be able to be free'd. With all of that info, and **assuming** my theory is correct, storing a log of what cannot be free'd might reveal a pattern that can help you fix this.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry I will try that. Sorry, I should've added a "What I've tried" cause I added gc.collect because I was getting that error but still got it afterward. I will add the generation though.

Comment: Oh. Well, maybe one of those other imports triggers `free()`, meaning I still might be on the right track theoretically. Understand that it is no theory that `free()` throws the `munmap_chunk()` error if the original pointer to `malloc` or `realloc` has changed. The theory part is "where in your code is this happening?" and I don't think it is in **your** code, at all.

Comment: Alrighty, I did some research and I believe your database is creating the error. I have found other `munmap_chunk()` errors related to python and mysql. I will admit that they are a bit old, but I don't see anything else in your imports that should be worrying about `free()`, and I still opine that this is the root of your problem. Can you try not using a database, at all, at least to see if it will run "forever" without the error? Also, remove `gc`. It isn't solving the problem, but it is "muddying the waters".

Comment: @MichaelGuidry So far I haven't gotten an error with adding generation=0. I'll try that if I do get the error. Thanks for helping too, I'm always used to people giving an answer, me asking for some clarification, then not getting a response lol.

Comment: My answers tend to be practically a complete rewrite of the code in the question with plenty of commenting, explanation and/or documentation. In this case, I don't have an actual answer ... just ideas and theories based on research of your error. Honestly, if you would have googled your error with some extra keywords (like python, mysql, etc), you would know as much as I do (cause that's all I did), and probably would have come to similar conclusions.

Comment: You may also want to consider that your database seems a bit pointless unless you start gathering statistics from it. You've basically negated it by adding in the JSON. You may also want to consider why you are saving the JSON if you are just going to overwrite it on every iteration. In your code's current state you could dump both the JSON and the database, and just roll with a dict.

Comment: @Micheal Guidry. Yeah, what youve said sounds familiar to what I've seen looking online. I made the post hoping that there might be an issue that wasn't with the database and cause it takes two days to reproduce the error. I just meant that you've  gotten back to me so thanks. In case of the json I have cause I have a phone app that uses it. A friend later on wanted the database for their own stats. Im considering just dropping the database and just using the JSON but making it so it adds instead of rewrites it since weve both found things that it may be the database.

Comment: I would suggest appending dicts to a list for an hour and then save the list to a unique json file for that hour. Also, I would suggest checking that the last object that is concocted in your loop is not identical to the current object being concocted. You are checking wind and rain A LOT. These values probably remain the same for a lot longer than the 60 and 5 times you are checking them.